# Why is which `executable software` and `software -v` refer to different things?

Tags: system, gnu-make

I was installing GNU make in an HPC cluster. There is pre-installed lower version make there.
And after I successfully configure and make the GNU make, I realized that another program is looking for `gmake`. So I just soft-link `gmake` to `make`. And add them to the $PATH.

The weird thing is, even if `which gmake` refers to the newly installed location, `gmake -v` showed the old version. I'd like to know how to fix it and in what order the system looks up the software.

Thank you.

Comment: Executables are searched in the order of directories in PATH. The directory with the new gmake should appear before the one with the old gmake. You might need to `hash -r` to update your shell's cached executable locations.

Comment: @Jens, thank you for answering. That's what I first thought. And I did put the new one at the beginning of $PATH and I think that's why `which gmake` leads to the new one. But then how would directly call `gmake` lead to the old one?

Comment: I have no good idea. Maybe some gremlin caused you to compile and install an old version? Can you compile and install the new gmake under your $HOME/some/prefix and verify if it shows the correct version when run as `$HOME/some/prefix/bin/make -v`? What's the name of the make-*-tar.gz you start with?

Comment: @Jens, I am pretty sure that I installed a new version and I did check it directly by calling it from its absolute path.

Comment: Do you have an alias or a shell function named gmake? Run `alias gmake` and `typeset -f gmake`.

Comment: I don't. But that's a great point to look at. I am just curious about the answer to the lookup order.